# Как обойти доступные типы кривоватой сборки?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Метод `Assembly.GetTypes()` возвращает список всех типов, объявленных в сборке. Однако, иногда бывает так, что некоторые зависимости для части объявленных в сборке типов недоступны, и некоторые типы не удаётся загрузить. При этом метод кидает исключение и не возвращает ничего.

Как сделать так, чтобы если некоторые типы не доступны, можно было бы просмотреть то, что удалось загрузить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно, в `MSDN` сказано, что результат все равно будет возвращен, но типы, которые не удалось отрефлектить, будут возвращены как `Nothing`:

> **ReflectionTypeLoadException**
>
> Сборка содержит один или несколько типов, которые не удается загрузить. Массив, возвращаемый свойством Types этого исключения, содержит объект Type для каждого загруженного типа и значение Nothing для каждого типа, который не удалось загрузить, в то время как свойство LoaderExceptions содержит исключение для каждого типа, который не был загружен.

*Соответственно, ловите этот эксепшн прямо там же, делайте необходимый роллбек для незагруженных типов и работайте с тем, что не `Nothing`.*